# Does the Fujifilm X100 have a limited number of shutter actuations, similar to focal-plane shutters?

Tags: shutter, fujifilm, shutter-actuations, fujifilm-x100

I'm trying to find out the expected shutter life of the Fujifilm X100. I've not been able to find any consistent specifications, apart from having a possibly-electronic leaf shutter. Has it got an electronic or mechanical one and how many actuations is it expected to manage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless Fuji, the manufacturer of the X100, publishes such a specification I doubt there is any reliable way to *estimate* the expected shutter life of the leaf shutter on the X100 unless you are willing to buy a large sample of X100 cameras and do the testing yourself. I am aware of no independent review/testing organization that publicly publishes results from such tests.

Keep in mind that the *Shutter Durability Rating* published by Canon, or the equivalent published by other manufacturers, is not an absolute number. There will be shutters that last significantly less than the rating for a particular camera and there will be shutters that last significantly longer. The number is most useful when comparing the expected life of the shutter assemblies in two different camera models from the same manufacturer, but not necessarily as useful when comparing models from different manufacturers. The methods used to arrive at such numbers may vary greatly from one camera maker to the next.